# Is it possible to prevent SSRS cache updating on parameter changed?

Tags: caching, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with a few parameters and one of them used to pass username, who used this report. I need this parameter, because a report works thru a proxy user interface and allways runs with only the one special account. Therefore I can't see real user name in SSRS logs, but proxy user interface knows his real  name. There is a parameter UserName I've added to the report, used to pass real username by proxy UI. No one query uses this parameter. I can see it only in "parameters" field of "Executionlog3" view and all seems to be fine, but there is an issue - how to force SSRS to ignore this additional "UserName" parameter changes?
There is an option "Never refresh" in Advanced tab of parameter properties. Is that what I need? But it does not work for me as I expected.

SSRS creates cache for every new value in a UserNeme parameter and every user needs to wait report building at a first run. In fact every user have individual cache for the one report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I've just moved UserName parameter to the end of parameters list. Now it works correct in URL mode.

"Never refresh" option works fine, when I browse the report in "standard" mode, via report viewer, it does not matter of UserName parameter position in parameters list. But via direct URL it were work incorrect, until I moved this parameter to the end of parameters list.

P.S. Sorry for my English